# Finding Shortest Path to Node with Given Value - Binary Tree

Tags: python, binary-tree, depth

Given a Binary Tree, I wanted to find the depth at which a specific value appears.

```
def find_depth_of_val(self, root, val):
    if not root:
        return 10000000
    if root.val == val:
        return 0
    return 1 + min(self.find_node(root.right, val), self.find_node(root.left, val))
```

This is the idea I had, you'll probably see a wild "return 10000000", which I used to make it so that if there is nothing else on a specific path, i.e. a leaf's next has been reached without finding the node we want, that the function knows the answer isn't there and doesn't return that possibility.

What I'm wondering is whether there's a better way to do this, one without using a random "return 10000000".

Edit: Someone gave me a solution in which I kind of change it to:

```
def find_depth_of_val(self, root, val):
    if not root:
        return None
    if root.val == val:
        return 0
    right_side = self.find_node(root.right, val)
    left_side = self.find_node(root.left, val)
    if right_side is None:
        return left_side
    elif left_side is None:
        return right_side
    else:
        return 1 + min(self.find_node(root.right, val), self.find_node(root.left, val))
```

In such a case like this, how should I type hint it considering we could be returning either None or an integer?
That said, I'm still open to seeing if anyone else has any different solution designs!!

Comment: Why not use the float infinity there. You can obtain it with `float('inf')` or `math.inf`.

Comment: Are your values unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks weird that `find_depth_of_val` has both `self` (a tree) and `root`  (another tree) as parameters.  Besides when you state your problem you talk of only one tree and `self` is actually not used in your method.

So assuming your values in the tree are unique, here is a solution.  The method returns `None` if no path is found or otherwise the depth.  `Optional[int]` means either an `int` or either `None`:

```py
def find_depth_of_val(self, val: int) -> Optional[int]:
    if self.val == val:
        return 0
    for node in (self.left, self.right):
        if node is not None:
            depth = node.find_depth_of_val(val)
            if depth is not None:
                return depth + 1
    return None
```